# Why is data not received from node server to angular client?

Tags: angularjs, node.js, mongodb

I've the following **SETUP**: AngularJS for UI, MongoDB for database and Node.js for server.

**FUNCTIONALITY** of my web page: It is tabular website and **3 tabs** to enter  details all of which is saved to Database and **one tab called EDIT/DOWNLOAD** to display specific details like 4-5 columns(fields) of each row(document) and further, for each document displayed there is an option to *edit or download details.*

**WORK FLOW:** on click of **tab EDIT/DOWNLOAD** a function [ say **viewDatabaseDetails()**] is called which in turns gets those details to be displayed as a table for each document in database.

- On click of **download button** again that specific document detail goes to NODE and then calls the specific document and save it all according to a template text file and send that file for download to client and deletes that file.
- On click of **edit button**, it again picks up data and populate those 3 tabs where user has to enter but here any changes made is updated in database instead of saving as a new document.

**ISSUE:** : When I click on function **viewDatabaseDetails()**, sometimes Angular displays data, sometimes it fails. Success of receiving data to display varies between 1-4 clicks on tab button to call **viewDatabaseDetails()**. Also, when I click on **download button**, sometimes files is received for download on the first click, sometimes after clicking on download button for 2-4 times file is received by client. I have checked node part on console, angular is sending all the details correctly every single time I **click on download button or viewDatabaseDetails()**, node is doing all the processing like data operations, creating file to send, creating proper response to  send all the documents details but somehow it is not being received by angular.

What might be happening is either the data is lost in network or timeout happens before receiving data/file as only server to client communication has issue. I checked network console in IE [i've a restriction to use only IE] upon success time taken is greater than time taken upon failure.

EDIT: 
Error explained according to below code: When  I click on view button in UI, sometimes data is displayed correctly, sometimes I get error as SyntaxError: Invalid Character.

UI:

```
<button ng-click="viewDatabase()"> View </button>
```

Controller:

```
$scope.viewDatabase = function(){
  $http.get('/getDatabase').success(function(response){
   $scope.outputs = response;
  }).error(function(){ 
      console.log("error");
  });
};
```

UI: for displaying response

```
<div>
 <table>
  <tr>
   <td>Name </td>
   <td>City </td>
   <td>Country </td>
  </tr>
  <tr ng-repeat="output in outputs">
   <td>{{output.Name}} </td>
   <td>{{output.City}} </td>
   <td>{{output.Country}} </td>
  </tr>
 </table>
</div>
```

Node and MongoDB code:

```
//other require statements
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var db = mongoose.connect(ConnectionString:port); 
var PropertyFileSchema = new Schema({
  Name: String,
  City: String,
  Country: String
 });
 PropertyFile = db.model('PropertyFile', PropertyFileSchema');
http.createServer(function(req,res){
//putting only required part of code
 if(req.url=="/getDatabase"){
  res.writeHead(200,{'content-type': 'application/json'});
  PropertyFile({},'Name City Country', function(err, docs){
   console.log(docs); //always displays if anything in database
   res.end(JSON.stringify(docs));
  });
 }
});
```

Comment: Can you please share your code ?

Comment: which part of code you want? post/get from angular and receiving in node, , database logic and sending output, right?

Comment: can you show me full code ?

Comment: I have edited my question with code, please check.